# Using unordered_map to store key-value pairs in STL

Tags: c++, data-structures, unordered-map

I have to store some data in my program as described below.

The data is high dimensional coordinates and the number of points in those coordinates. Following would be a simple example (with coordinate dimension 5):

```
  coordinate        # of points
(3, 5, 3, 5, 7)          6
(6, 8, 5, 8, 9)          4
(4, 8, 6, 7, 9)          3
```

Please note that even if I use 5 dimensions as an example, the actual problem is of 20 dimensions. The coordinates are always integers.

I want to store this information in some kind of data structure. The first thing that comes to my mind is a hash table. I tried `unordered_map` in STL. But cannot figure out how to use the coordinates as the key in `unordered_map`. Defining it as:

```
unordered_map<int[5], int> umap;
```

or,

```
unordered_map<int[], int> umap;
```

gives me a compilation error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"gives me a compilation error."* Did you happen read what the compiler error said? How about sharing the knowledge with us? Also, read this: [mcve]

Comment: C arrays are fundamentally different than other types of variables. For example, you can't directly assign to them, and you can't put them in standard library containers like what you're trying to do. Try using `std::array`.

Answer (score 1):

`unordered_map` needs to know how to **hash** your coordinates. In addition, it needs a way to compare coordinates for **equality**.

You can wrap your coordinates in a `class` or `struct` and provide a custom [operator ==](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) to compare coordinate points. Then you need to specialise [std::hash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) to be able to use your `Point` struct as a key in `unordered_map`. While comparing coordinates for equality is fairly straightforward, it is up to you to decide how coordinates are hashed. The following is an overview of what you need to implement:

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cmath>

class Point
{
    std::vector<int> coordinates;

public:

    inline bool operator == (const std::vector<int>& _other)
    {
        if (coordinates.size() != _other.size())
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (uint c = 0; c < coordinates.size(); ++c)
        {
            if (coordinates[c] != _other[c])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<Point>
    {
        std::size_t operator() (const Point& _point) const noexcept
        {
            std::size_t hash;

            // See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine
            // for an example of hash implementation for std::vector.
            // Using Boost just for this might be an overkill - you could use just the hash_combine code here.

            return hash;
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<Point, int> points;

    // Use points...    

    return 0;
}
```

In case you know how many coordinates you are going to have and you can *name* them like this

```
struct Point
{
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int x3;
    // ... 
}
```

you could use a header-only [hashing library](https://gitlab.com/cantordust/abacus_hash) I wrote exactly for this purpose. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I think an `std::array` would probably be more appropriate here to store coordinates if the number of dimensions is known.

Comment: @FeiXiang I agree - either array or even a tuple as a member of a template class accepting a type and a size_t for the number of elements. The advantage of using `std::vector` is that you can store points with a different number of coordinates in the same container.

Answer (score 1):

##### Hacky way

I've seen this being used in programming competitions for ease of use. You can convert the set of points to a string(concatenate each coordinate and separate them with a space or any other special character) and then use `unordered_map<string, int>`

```
unordered_map<string, int> map; int p[5] = {3, 5, 3, 5, 7};

string point = to_string(p[0]) + " " + to_string(p[1]) + " " to_string(p[2]) + " " to_string(p[3]) + " " to_string(p[4]);

map[point] = 6;
```